# Why is heated Helium used for tank pressurisation in Falcon 1?

Tags: spacex, design, tanks, helium, falcon-1

Here in [Falcon 1 user guide](http://www.georing.biz/usefull/Falcon1UsersGuide.pdf), in table 2-1 in page 8, heated Helium is mentioned as used for tank pressurisation. What will be the temperature of such He and why is heated He used?

[image: Location in the linked article for reference.]

Comment: Sorry Karthik, didn't notice you were asking about the first reference to it, added an image to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you haven't already read all of the answers to questions like [Why does the Falcon 9 require a helium pressurization system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21246/12102) and [How does tank pressurization work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20648/12102) and [Why Use Helium?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20245/12102) and [Why do pressure-fed systems have to be pressurized with helium or nitrogen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9311/12102) this might be a good time. To "why is heated He used?" isn't the answer just that that's what generates the pressure?

Comment: @uhoh I take the question to mean "why _heated_ helium."

Comment: It probably has something to do with adiabatic cooling. This one of the gas laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws#Gay-Lussac's_law When volume is constant, if pressure drops then temperature will drop too. If it drops too far, the cooling is so extreme that it can crack the metal tank. Therefore some kind of heating system is necessary to keep the temperature more or less constant. Kinda ironic that way.

Comment: @WayneConrad as do I. Isn't *the heating* the helium what causes the helium to become pressurized, "the heating" being the thing that actually "generates the pressure?" A tank of liquid helium at its 1 bar boiling point will have a slow boil-off rate, nothing close to enough to help the *tons per second* of propellants out of the tank. Isn't *the heating* of the helium the thing that does the propellant-helping?

Comment: @uhoh Oh, it's liquid He?  I guess I should have known that, but I didn't (until just now).

Comment: @WayneConrad I don't know for sure either way. But it's pretty cold - cold enough [to freeze oxygen](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19661/12102) in the F9. The tanks are [so small](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22076/12102) in the F9 that it's hard to imagine they can do so much displacement if not starting out as a liquid. Either way, heating is used to add pressurization.

Comment: If gaseous helium is stored in a high pressure tank, its temperature will drop a lot during expansion. To compensate the temperature drop and to get more volume per mass, the helium is heated after expansion.

Comment: @uhoh I guess adding a lot of He to a rigid container too can increase the pressure.

Comment: @Uwe you mean by Joule Thompson effect. what is the inversion temperature for He? Would it heat up or cool upon expansion? Also, what is the source of hearing if it's going to cool?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn thanks for making my question easier to understand!

Comment: On page 9 of the Falcon 1's user's guide, it says the helium is stored in composite over-wrapped inconel tanks, so it is presumably stored as a high pressure gas.